# DirectX9 within Windows Forms

Tags: c++, winforms, directx

I need to integrate a DirectX9 device in a C++ Windows Form - how do I do that?

On the one hand I got my DirectX application....

```
HWND hWnd;
WNDCLASSEX wc;

ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

RegisterClassEx(&wc);

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "WindowClass", "Engine",
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                      NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

m_D3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;

// creates device
m_D3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &m_Device);
```

and on the other hand I got my Windows Form

```
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
```

How do I merge this?

Comment: Remember you do not want to create your Device until the window is actually shown.  On WindowsXP this will be an issue.  So usually I override OnShown and init there.  Also remember to use a D3D9_EX Device on Windows Vista-7 as it handles resources for you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some info from this Source  : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/Irrational_Thinking.aspx

```
//File: DX9Form.cpp
#include "DX9Form.h"

using namespace Forms_DX9;
using namespace globals;

void DX9Form::initD3D(HWND hHandle)
{

    globals::d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    // create the Direct3D interface

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    // create a struct to hold various device information

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp)); // clear out the struct for use

    d3dpp.Windowed = true; // program windowed, not fullscreen

    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD; // discard old frames

    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hHandle;
    // set the window to be used by Direct3D

    // create a device class using this information
    // and information from the d3dpp stuct
    globals::d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
            D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
            hHandle,
            D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
            &d3dpp,
            &globals::d3ddev);
}

void DX9Form::render(void)
{

    // clear the window to a deep blue
    globals::d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, 
                              D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 40, 100), 1.0f, 0);
    globals::d3ddev->BeginScene(); // begins the 3D scene

    // do 3D rendering on the back buffer here
    globals::d3ddev->EndScene(); // ends the 3D scene
    globals::d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    // displays the created frame
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your DirectX code in the form's OnLoad() method override or Load event handler.  You'll need its Handle property:

```
protected:
    void OnLoad(EventArgs^ e) override {
        HWND hWnd = (HWND)(void*)this->Handle;
        YourDirectXInitializeFunction(hWnd);
    }
```

Comment: i tried that approach, but I do not get my directX cpp code running cause it's not managed :(

Comment: Well, doesn't matter, C++/CLI has no trouble calling native code.  Pretty much the only reason to ever use it.  You are doing something wrong but left no breadcrumbs at all to guess what.  Not even an error message.  Update your question.